# Mock patch specific instance of class

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

How to mock a specific instance of a class using `patch`?

In my test file I have:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.instance_of_my_class = myClass()
```

one of the tests then calls a function in `myClass` that I wish to mock the return value of.

I can do so like this.

```
self.instance_of_my_class.cool_fuction = Mock(return_value=(True, True))
```

I wish to do this using `with patch` so that the mock does not persist into the other tests, **or** to, in some way **unset** the mock.

However, `patch` requires a string like `"package.module.Class.attribute"` as it's target so putting

```
with patch("self.instance_of_my_class") as mock:
      mock.return_value.cool_fuction.return_value = (True, True)
```

fails with traceback

`AssertionError: No module named 'self'`

If I patch the class like

```
with patch("functions_folder.my_script.myClass") as mock:
      mock.return_value.cool_fuction.return_value = (True, True)
```

the wrong instance is patched and `mock.called` returns `False`

The test looks like:

```
def test_foo_function(self):
    result = self.instance_of_my_class.foo_function()
    self.assertTrue(result[0]["confirmed"])
```

and `foo_function` calls on `cool_function` which I want to mock return `(True, True)`

Comment: I think you're looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object, but you shouldn't mock the thing you're supposed to be testing - test doubles are for collaborators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @johnsharpe for pointing out the answer.

with the same setUpClass at the start of Test_myClass as I had:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.instance_of_my_class = myClass()
```

working test case now looks like:

```
@patch.object(myClass, "cool_function")
def test_foo_function(self, mock):
    mock.return_value = (True, True)
    
    result = self.instance_of_my_class.foo_function()

    self.assertTrue(result[0]["confirmed"])
    self.assertTrue(mock.called)
```